# I want to save data in a matrix / array form in java

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I'm getting data from LDAP iteratively, so at one time I get values in key value pair form.

```
mailId :abc@xyz.com
UserId :abc
Locked :0 or any number with locked period
```

I want to read these values for all the users to create a text file like below seperated by tab or ; so that I can parse the file later. Which is the fastest datatype or collection I can use in java to implement this?

```
userId   mailId   Locked
abc    abc@xyz.com    0
```

Below is working code which adds this data to a linkedlist.

```
    while(ae.hasMoreElements())
            {
                Attribute atr = (Attribute) ae.next();
                String attributeID = atr.getID();

                              if((attributeID.toString()).equals("uid")|(attributeID.toString()).equals("mail")|(attributeID.toString()).equals("lockoutTime")) {

                    Enumeration vall = atr.getAll();
                    System.out.println(vall);
                    for(Enumeration val = atr.getAll(); val.hasMoreElements();) {
                        String value = (String)val.nextElement();
                        System.out.println(value);
                        uidList.add(value);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I believe it can easily be stored in HashMap with key as userId and value as object containing (userId, mailId, locked)

Comment: I'd not bother about the "faster" part because that would probably be premature (micro-)optimization. Instead you should think about making the code easier to understand, less error prone etc. - to achieve that you could provide a class that is able to hold the data you need (user id, mail id, locked). If you don't know what data you'll get then a map might be easier to use with the key being the attribute name (that would require more memory though as well as some more thoughts on how to handle differences between users when it comes to attribute names).

Comment: If you really are concerned with micro-optimizing, the line where you check for equality with "uid", "mail" and "lockoutTime" has a couple issues. One, the toString() call is redundant because attributeID is already a String. Two, you are using | instead of the shortcut operator ||. This causes unnecessary comparisons to be made. Fixing these issues will also help readability.